# Listing attributes for users in a specific organizational unit in Active Directory. Some not showing

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to list some attributes for users objects that reside in a specific OU and it's Sub-directories. I'm pretty much there except that for some reason, DisplayName and WhenCreated do not show when I tried to get that data with this code.

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$OUpath = 'OU=Locations,DC=Domain,DC=com'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object DistinguishedName, enabled, GivenName, 
Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, 
WhenCreated
```

However, if I choose to go about it this way values for those attributes appear.

```
Get-AdUser -filter * -Properties * | select DisplayName, WhenCreated, DistinguishedName, 
enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, 
UserPrincipalName
```

I can't seem to understand what that is.

Comment: the default for the AD cmdlets is to return _only a limited number of properties_. the default ones are easy to see ... send the output of a call using your username and send that to `Select-Object -Property *`. you need to use the `-Properties` parameter of the AD cmdlets to get more than the default. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#description) says:

> This cmdlet retrieves a default set of user object properties. To retrieve additional properties use the Properties parameter.

So yes, you will need to tell it that you want more properties than the default set. Yes, you can use `*`, but that will return every attribute that has a value, which can be a lot of data that you aren't going to use. To save bandwidth and time, specify only the ones you plan on using:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, WhenCreated, DistinguishedName, Enabled, `
    GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName `
| Select DisplayName, WhenCreated, DistinguishedName, Enabled, `
    GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
```